# Has anyone successfully used MPOAuth on iPhone to connect with twitter?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, oauth

My project builds fine but when it gets to line pasted bellow it crashes with the following message.

CODE:

```
oauthAPI = [[MPOAuthAPI alloc] initWithCredentials:credentials
        authenticationURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://twitter.com/oauth/"]
         andBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://twitter.com/"]];
```

ERROR:

> Assertion failure in
>   -[MPOAuthAuthenticationMethodOAuth initWithAPI:forURL:withConfiguration:],
>   /Project/MPOAuth/MPOAuthAuthenticationMethodOAuth.m:49
>
> Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
>   reason: 'Incorrect number of oauth
>   authorization methods'

Comment: AFAIK - you'd have to do auth and other api requests to api.twitter.com, not to twitter.com directly. May be wrong though.

Answer (score 1):

twitter now uses OAuth as authentication mechanism. You will have to change your oauthAutoConfig.plist

The entry for twitter should look like this

[image]